# Is there a way to get some function called on every thread that gets created?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want some function to be called (so it can do some initialization) in any thread that is started.
The threads that are started are outside of my control, so I can't modify all code that starts the threads.

In more detail:
On windows one should install a terminate handler in every thread. ([std::set_terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-terminate-crt?view=vs-2019)
(yes this deviates from the standard but that's not the point here).
So basically I want to set my handler in all threads in my application.

Comment: Certainly, manage your thread creation with a `class` that does this.

Comment: FWIW: This is why, If you ever are called upon to write a library that needs to create its own threads, you should use a thread _[factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)_, and give the library client the option to _[inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)_ their own custom factory object.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the API level, however for your specific need on a termination handler you can install a top level exception handler which will terminate that specific thread once called ([SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Windows installs this handler in each thread.

Comment: We already had this filter installed, but unfortunately it doesn't get called in all cases. For example when an exception escapes a method marked as noexcept, it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such API in the standard library that would allow registering a callback to be called by all new threads. I don't know about other system specific API, but the POSIX threads do not provide such callbacks either.

Only if you can control the code that creates the threads, can you make it call your function at the start of the thread.